# convergence in law in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In my probability professor's notes there's this lemma given as obvious, but I am not able to prove its truth.

> Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $X$ be random variables with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
>
> Prove that the following to statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. the sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in law to $X$.
> 2. for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we have that $(\langle u,X_n \rangle)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in law to $\langle u,X \rangle$.

I am able to prove the easy direction (i.e. 1. $\implies$ 2.).

Can somebody provide me a proof of 2. $\implies$ 1. ?

Comment: Pick $u = e_i = (0, \dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)$ (one is at the $i$th position) for $i = 1,\dots, d$

Comment: I thought about it, but I can't see how it helps though. I mean, how can the convergence in law of the components imply the convergence in law of the whole random variable? Just take for example $f(x,y) = max(1,xy)$, I don't see in this case how it can help.

Comment: I don't think this is obvious. This is the famous  Cramér-Wold device; it is usually proven via characteristic functions.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Cramér-Wold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem). A proof is given in Billingsley's *Probability and Measure* (p.383 Theorem 29.4). This is a very standard reference.

The way in Billingsley to prove "`2` implies `1`" is using the characteristic functions (and the [continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem)). A key observation is that for any $t\in{\bf R}^d$,
$$
\varphi_X(t)= \varphi_{\langle t,X\rangle}(1)
$$
where $\varphi_X$ denotes the characteristic function of the random vector $X$ and $\varphi_{\langle t,X\rangle}$ is the characteristic function of the random variable $\langle t,X\rangle$.

Comment: Is the result is false if we just assume $\langle e_i, X_n\rangle$ converges in law, $e_i$ being the standard basis vectors?

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I believe convergence in law for each component is not sufficient. Consider for instance $X\sim N(0,1)$. Note that $X$ is symmetric. One can find an example that $X_n\Rightarrow X$ *and* $X_n\Rightarrow -X$ but $X_n+X_n\not\Rightarrow X+(-X)$. So by the theorem above, one cannot have $(X_n, X_n)\Rightarrow (X, -X)$.